# Removing Azure SQL Managed Instance admin user

Tags: azure-sql-managed-instance

I would like to change the [Azure SQL Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/sql-managed-instance-paas-overview) admin (this is not for the Active Directory Admin).  I do not see any way to do this directly.  I am guessing that if I create another sysadmin user, and then delete the current Managed Instance admin user which is also a sysadmin.  This might force the backend to fall back and look for any sysadmin available to fill the vacated Managed Instance admin.  I have not tried this because the current Azure SQL Managed Instance is in use. I am afraid the Azure SQL Managed Instance might blow up if it loses its Managed Instance admin.

What will occur if one deletes the Managed Instance admin user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect to the instance name from [Azure Data Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/what-is-azure-data-studio) and create a new admin user:

1. Go to the master db and run the create login script

   ```
   CREATE LOGIN newusername WITH PASSWORD = 'password123'
   ```
2. Go to your database and run

   ```
    use databasename
    go

    Create user [newusername] from login [newusername]
    go
    exec sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'newusername';
   ```
3. Remove your old user admin

Comment: I have done steps 1 and 2 already.  I have not done step 3.  Have you done step 3 and saw no issues with your sql mi afterwards?

Comment: @ppham I've done the step 3 and no issue at all. One thing I forgot to mention is you need to apply step 2 all your databases on that instance. Please consider upvoting and accepting the answer if you found it helpful.